# Jupyter Scipy stats invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scipy, jupyter-notebook

```
t, pvalue = ttest_ind(iris_dataframe[sepal width (cm)'][group1],
iris_dataframe['sepal width (cm)'][group2], axis=0, equal_var=False)
print 't statistic %0.3f p‐value %0.3f' % (t, pvalue)
```

File "", line 1
    stats.ttest_ind(iris_dataframe[sepal width (cm)'][group1],
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Whats wrong with this syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed first single quote before "sepal".

t, pvalue = ttest_ind(iris_dataframe['sepal width (cm)'][group1],
iris_dataframe['sepal width (cm)'][group2], axis=0, equal_var=False)

This might remove your syntax error.